# .net Howto find substrings with placeholder

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, search

I've got a list of Strings, and I want to check every String if it contains a certain substring.

Problem is: There should be placeholders allowed.

E.g.:
I'm searching for 
`"customer-id", "customer id", "customers id"`
-> my search string looks like this: `"customer{2}id"` (whereas {2} stands for the number of placeholder characters -> between 0 and 2).

Of course this won't work with

```
teststring.indexof("customer{2}id")
```

Tried also:

```
Dim r as new Regex("customer??id")
```

but this only throws a nested qualifier something something exception.
As I am not that geek in regular expressions I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` is a quantifier in regular expressions (and not a place holder for a single character). that means it quantifies the preceding element. That can be a character, a character class or a group.

There exist 4 Quantifiers in regex.

1. `{x,y}` where x is the minimum amount to match and y is the maximum amount to match. You can also put only one digit `{4}` that would match exactly 4 occurrences.
2. `+` means one or more, is the same as `{1,}`
3. `*` means zero or more, is the same as `{0,}`
4. `?` means zero or one, is the same as `{0,1}`

I think you need something like

```
customer.{0,2}id
```

`.` is a special character in regex and matches any character (except newlines)

So this regex would match strings like:

> customerid
>   customer id
>   customer-id
>   customer#+id
>   customerXXid

You can replace the `.` by a more defined character class, e.g. if you only want to allow a space and a hyphen, create you own character class and add the characters you want to allow.

```
customer[ -]{0,2}id
```

This regex would match strings like:

> customerid
>   customer id
>   customer -id
>   customer- id
>   customer--id

Further information:

- [Regular Expression Quick Start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) on www.regular-expressions.info
- [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) on msdn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can try something like:

```
customer.{0,2}id
```

That would search for a string starting with `customer` followed by 0-2 characters followed by `id`.

So basically `customer.{0,n}id` where `n` is from your `indexof` example: `customer{n}id`.

Note that `.` matches any character (including new lines in some situations).